# seperate build and install target machines

Tags: ros, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS community. I have dedicated build server for all ROS packages. Once a package is successfully build I want to transfer only package binaries to target machine.
The target machine has ROS installed. Currently I am following approach.

- catkin_make -install -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX package_name
- compress the install directory
- transfer and decompress the ROS package
- Update ROS_PACKAGE_PATH on target and
- rosrun pacakge_name executable

However ROS is failing to locate the package.
I am guessing I need to update the scripts setup scripts generated in build process. However, these scripts have hardcoded values of build project path so cannot directly copy paste.
I even tried to replace catkin workspace directory path with installed path on target machine. Still rosrun cannot find the package.

Can anyone please guide me in this regard?
I am using ROS 1.11.8 on Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192327/seperate-build-and-install-target-machines/) by [Jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/20150/jarvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pachuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20216/pachuc/) on 2014-09-16**:
Were you able to figure something out?

**Comment by [Jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/20150/jarvis/) on 2014-10-28**:
Yes. I have wrote a script to provide this functionality. One requirement for my script to work is to  provide install rule for each package and run catkin_make install to build packages. If you need I can upload it in separate GitHub repo and provide link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have come up with vary ugly way of doing this.
On build server I have a script which creates compressed version of package installable. e.g
catkin_make install --pkg pkg_name -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX pkg_install
zip -r package.zip pkg_install

Now I can copy this compressed package install directory on my target machine.
Target machine has the ROS installed but no package source code.

On target machine I have another script which performs following tasks:

1. create a workspace directory
2. create ".catkin" and ".rosinstall" files inside the workspace. (This marks the workspace as catkin_workspace)
3. copy ros setup files from ros_install_directory to worksapce directory
   This is initialization parts done once per target
   For per package
   The package is unzipped in tmp dir
   The package contents are something like
   tmp/ros_package/lib
   tmp/ros_package/share
   ...
   Now I copy content of
   copy tmp/ros_package/lib/* to workspace/lib/<package_name>/
   copy tmp/ros_package/share/* to workspace/lib/<package_name>/
   ....

This process actually worked. I am able to run newly installed nodes on target without having its source code.

However, the scripts are very complicated and not very easy to maintain.

Can someone suggest a better way?

---

Originally posted by [Jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/20150/jarvis/) with karma: 67 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1